# C Multiple Strtok to determine delimiter

Tags: c, strtok

I'm writing a C program where the user can input a string of 1-3 digits followed by a backslash and then another 1-3 digits or they can enter 1-3 digits, followed by a comma, then another 1-3 digits and there is no limit to how many times they can iterate this.

I need to determine whether the input delimiter is a backslash or comma (to determine what to do with the numbers) and put the numbers into an array.

The way I was thinking of doing this was to using strtok as follows. The string is inputted as char *token.

```
op_tok1 = strtok(token, "\\");
if(op_tok1 != NULL)
{
        /* Process numbers */
        return;
}

op_tok2 = strtok(token, ",");
if(op_tok2 != NULL)
{
    /* Process other numbers */
    return;
}
```

This works for anything delimetered with a backslash, but not with a comma. I believe this is because strtok messes with the token variable. Is this true? Is there a better way to go about this? thanks!

Comment: Have you tried creating a copy of `token` for use with the comma strtok?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are certainly ways I'd consider better. If you can depend reasonably well on the format of the input (i.e., really being three digits followed by one of the allowed delimiters), you could do something like:

```
char *pos = 0;

while (2 == sscanf(input+pos, "%d%c", &number, &delimiter)) {
    if ('\\' == delimiter)
        process_backslash(number);
    else if (',' == delimiter)
        process_comma(number);
    else
        error_invalid_delimiter(delimiter);
    pos += 4;
}
```

Comment: I agree that the `sscanf` approach is definitely better in this case.

Comment: If you *can't* trust the input to be well formatted, you can use a similar approach with `getchar()`.  Essentially, read and validate one character at a time instead of slurping them all up at once with `sscanf()`.  That should be better than `strtok()` while still giving you more power to detect invalid input.

Answer (score 0):

Others have posted better solutions - strtok is not really suitable for this task. However, answering the first question - is strtok changing the underlying string, Yes (it's evil in my mind how it works. Many a young player has fallen into this trap):

`strtok` replaces token with `\0` (Null terminator) and passes the start of the string. Subsequent calls to `strtok(NULL, <token>)` continue scanning the string, looking for the next token, which does not need to be the same.

Therefore you could do:

```
op_tok1 = strtok(token, "\\");
if(op_tok1 != NULL)
{
    /* Process numbers */
    return;
}

op_tok2 = strtok(NULL, ",");
if(op_tok2 != NULL)
{
   /* Process other numbers */
   return;
}
```

Also beware it is **not thread safe**.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use `scanf()`?

```
~/tmp$ cat test.c
#include <stdio.h>
int main(int argc, char ** argv) {
    int i;
    char c;
    while (2 == scanf("%d%[\\.]",&i,&c)) {
        printf("Int %d\nChar %c\n", i, c);
    }
}
```

... worked for me.

```
~/tmp$ gcc test.c && echo "123.456\789.4" | ./a.out
Int 123
Char .
Int 456
Char \
Int 789
Char .
~/tmp$
```